# IS there any mechanism to deliver secrets to the iOS App in a secure manner

Tags: ios, swift, security, cocoa-touch

I want to send particular key value pairs (secrets) to the app dynamically.. So by doing some investigation it seems we have apple remote assets concept (didn't find any documentation though)..

Please help me out to find some options to do this and also a documentation on apple remote assets if have any.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How do you want it delivered?  Is it been pushed to or pulled by the app?

Comment: pushed by app !

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty comprehensive article:

https://nshipster.com/secrets/

TL;DR: Don't do this.

The correct thing to do is to embed your third party API secrets in a server that you control instead, authenticate your client with that server and have them call an API on your server to prove they have the correct authorisation and then have the server call the third party API.

But if you really must send a secret down to the client, then use one of:

- On-Demand Resources: Download a data asset containing a plain-text secret.
  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html
- CloudKit Database: Set secrets in a private database in your CloudKit Dashboard. (Bonus: Subscribe to changes for automatic credential rolling functionality)
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkitjs/cloudkit/database
- Background Updates: Push secrets silently to clients as soon as they come online via APNS.
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app